# How do I find out what my default terminal text editor is?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, text-editor

While reading the git introductory material, I read a piece that brought this question to mind.

**How do I use the Terminal to find out what my Default Text Editor is?**

**Are there a General Commands that I can use to find this out?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The default editor is as defined by the `EDITOR`, or `VISUAL`, environment variable(s).

The default editor is `vi` if neither were defined. Add

```
export EDITOR="/bin/nano"
```

to your `~/.bashrc` file to set, for example, `nano` as your default editor.

To see if the environment variable is set, you can use

```
printenv | grep EDITOR
```

or

```
set | grep EDITOR
```

One can dereference the value of the named environment variable by prefixing it with a "$"

```
$ echo $EDITOR
```

or

```
$ echo $VISUAL
```

Comment: @heemayl: Thanks for your edit, as I forgot to format properly. However, I very specifically wanted to say `$EDITOR` and not `EDITOR`. Why? Because one refers to the environment variable by preceding the name with a $ sign. For example `$ $EDITOR bla.txt` or `echo $EDITOR` or ... So, I am going to reverse the deletion of the $ sign.

Comment: Yes, and I wanted to refer to the value of the variable.

Comment: @heemayl: I'll do an edit,see if you like it, and then delete these comments. It will be a few hours until I can do it though.

Comment: @heemayl: Is this O.K. with you?

Comment: @DougSmythies , identifiers (aka names that define i.e. a variable) are language and context dependent. if you're going to use the $ sign, it should be to dereference the variable, meaning that you're accessing the value of the variable.  you don't use the $ sign when assigning a value to that variable; so when you refer to the name of one, you do not use it.

Answer (score 20):

In Ubuntu, there is a generic `editor` command which is set by the Debian alternatives system.

If you do:

```
editor foobar.txt
```

the file will be opened using the original editor e.g. `vim`, `nano` which is prioritized as `editor` currently.

You can check the details with:

```
update-alternatives --display editor
```

To set a new editor as `editor`:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

---

Also note that `bash` checks some environment variables for tasks related to it, to be exact `bash` checks `VISUAL`, `EDITOR` one after another. If unset, `bash` defaults to `nano` (unless an editor you've installed has overridden this).

Some processes spawned from `bash` check these environment variables too.

Comment: Are you sure it's `emacs`? If I unset `VISUAL` and `EDITOR` e.g. `sudo visudo` runs in `nano` for me

Comment: Check my answer guys, I've updated it a bit, with man page exerpt

Comment: This is a peculiarity specific to Ubuntu, because it has the Debian alternatives system. On systems, without it `git` has to check `EDITOR` variable

Comment: Actually no I'm sure it can't be `emacs`, since `emacs` is not installed by default. Installing `emacs` probably overrode your previous configuration.

Comment: this one should be correct answer. imho

Answer (score 4):

There is actually `git var -l` which allows you to list the variables, including `GIT_EDITOR` variable. Here's mine (private info is unset of course):

```
$ git var -l
user.name=*****
user.email=****
GIT_COMMITTER_IDENT=****
GIT_AUTHOR_IDENT=****
GIT_EDITOR=editor
GIT_PAGER=pager
```

As heemayl already pointed out, `editor` command is the one set by `/etc/alternatives/editor`. In my case, that's `nano` (which I assume is default for Ubuntu, because I don't remember consciously making an effort to change my default editor).

But on other systems other than Ubuntu (or I should say which have no Debian's alternatives system) , there is no `editor`.  Let's, however read up the `man git`:

> GIT_EDITOR
>
> This environment variable overrides $EDITOR and $VISUAL. It is used
>   by several Git commands when, on interactive mode, an editor is to
>   be launched. See also git-var(1) and the core.editor option in git-
>   config(1).

And if we look through `git-var` it tells us

> The order of preference is the $GIT_EDITOR environment variable, then
>   core.editor configuration, then $VISUAL, then $EDITOR, and then the
>   default chosen at compile time, which is usually vi.

Thus it is a mere perculiarity of Ubuntu that it has Debian's alternatives system. On other systems which don't have Debian's alternatives systems it would default to `vi`